# Problem of importing some special characters in HTML

Tags: html, xml

content of the html file is as follows:

```
<p>

被尊称为&ldquo;高贵的&rdquo;

</p>
```

method1:

```
Import["C:\\Users\\HyperGroups\\Desktop\\test.html", "XML"]
```

XML`Parser`XMLGet::nfprserr: Entity 'ldquo' was not found at Line: 2 Character: 12 in C:\Users\HyperGroups\Desktop\test.html. >>

XML`Parser`XMLGet::nfprserr: Entity 'rdquo' was not found at Line: 2 Character: 22 in C:\Users\HyperGroups\Desktop\test.html. >>

```
(*
    XMLObject[Document][{},XMLElement[p,{},{被尊称为\[EntityStart]ldquo\[EntityEnd]高贵的\[EntityStar
t]rdquo\[EntityEnd]}],{}]
*)
```

method2:

```
Import["C:\\Users\\HyperGroups\\Desktop\\test.html", "XMLObject"]

(*
    XMLObject[Document][{XMLObject[Declaration][Version->1.0,Standalone->yes]},XMLElement[html
,{version->-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN,{http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/,xmlns}->h
ttp://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml},{XMLElement[body,{},{XMLElement[p,{},{被尊称为"高贵的"}]}]}],{}]
*)
```

Why method1 generates those information, and how to avoid that and get the result just like method2 ?