# Importing HTML loses the Nested tags relation

Tags: html, xml

```
str="<div id=\"1\" style='display:none;'>
<pre class=\"prettyprint lang-mma\">
<pre class=\"Input\" style=\"white-space:nowrap; padding-left:50px;     background-color:#FF359A;\">
<code>
`varCode`
</code>
</pre>
</pre>
</div>";

xml1 = ImportString[str, "XML"]
(*
    XMLObject[Document][{},XMLElement[div,{id->1,style->display:none;},{XMLElement[pre,{class-
>prettyprint lang-mma},{XMLElement[pre,{class->Input,style->white-space:nowrap; padding-le
ft:50px; background-color:#FF359A;},{XMLElement[code,{},{`varCode`}]}]}]}],{}]
*)
```

We can see the two pre tags are nested, and the result is as expected.

```
html = ExportString[xml1[[2]], "HTMLFragment"];
Import[Export["test.html", html, "Text"], "XML"]

(*
    <div id="1" style="display:none;"><pre class="prettyprint lang-mma"><pre class="Input" sty
le="white-space:nowrap; padding-left:50px; background-color:#FF359A;"><code>`varCode`</cod
e></pre></pre></div>
*)
```

### Note

---

In this method of Importing html, two pre tags are not nested.

```
Import[Export["test.html", html, "Text"], "XMLObject"]

(*
    XMLObject[Document][{XMLObject[Declaration][Version->1.0,Standalone->yes]},XMLElement[html
,{version->-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN,{http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/,xmlns}->h
ttp://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml},{XMLElement[body,{},{XMLElement[div,{id->1,style->display:non
e;},{XMLElement[pre,{class->prettyprint lang-mma},{}],XMLElement[pre,{class->Input,style->
white-space:nowrap; padding-left:50px; background-color:#FF359A;},{XMLElement[code,{},{`va
rCode`}]}]}]}]}],{}]
*)
```

Why using XMLObject? more robust than XML, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/importing-malformed-xml-import-xmlobject-vs-importstring-xml) is an example, 
and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84524/problem-of-importing-some-special-characters-in-html)  is another example.

Many times, `Import` as XML failed.

My question is why `XMLObject` is different with `XML`, and how to Import the HTML file as Nested tags.

Is this a bug or some feature of XMLObject?

Comment: You are quiet right.  I have absolutely no idea why there is an inconsistency.  My best guess is that it has to do with the doctype(or whatever the equivalent is for xml).